# WordNet Lemmatizer don't it lemmatize all inflections of a word in CSV file

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, lemmatization

I want to lemmatize all words in sentences(CSV file, and this file contains tweets) for our goal to reduce the frequency of words. By using wordnet lemmatizer. I know defult for lemmatizer is NOUN but I want to lemmatize on many pos tag.

For example, all these words death, died, dead to become their root is die.
Another example threaten not return to root threat and terroristic, terrorist, terrorism to the root.

I think, I want to tokenization of words, not sentences and lemmatize it.

I was trying to use this code but the result not good like example above and bombing don't to return to bomb and so on. ()

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()


def nltk_tag_to_wordnet_tag(nltk_tag):
    if nltk_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif nltk_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif nltk_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif nltk_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return None

def lemmatize_sentence(sentence):
    #tokenize the sentence and find the POS tag for each token
    nltk_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
    #tuple of (token, wordnet_tag)
    wordnet_tagged = map(lambda x: (x[0], nltk_tag_to_wordnet_tag(x[1])), nltk_tagged)
    lemmatized_sentence = []
    for word, tag in wordnet_tagged:
        if tag is None:
            #if there is no available tag, append the token as is
            lemmatized_sentence.append(word)
        else:
            #else use the tag to lemmatize the token
            lemmatized_sentence.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, tag))
    return " ".join(lemmatized_sentence)
# Lemmatizing
df['Lemmatize'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: lemmatize_sentence(x))
print(df.head())
```

Thank you for help me